# Understanding a Mumps statement

Tags: mumps

What is the meaning of this statement: `S A=$P(P,,2) I S`?

Answer (score 8):

This may not be valid syntax based on the MUMPS implementation. For example, Intersystem Cache will generate a syntax error, since the second parameter passed to the piece function is blank.

The `$P` or `$PIECE(str, delim, num)`, function will return the *num*-th segment of *str* when delimited by *delim*.  So, `p("a^b^c","^",2)` returns "b". When *delim* is the empty string, `$P` will return the empty string. However, there can be a difference between passing nothing and an empty string.

`S A=$P(P,,2)` says to set the variable *A* to the value returned by the piece function.

Finally, `I S`, says that if the value of variable *S* evaluates to true, continue executing the rest of this line. The `I` or `IF` command also has the side effect of setting the `$T` variable to 1 if the expression is true, or 0, if the expression is false. This is important if your line of code is followed by an else statement, which uses `$T` to determine whether the previous if statement returned false.

Comment: Can't add anything, except that in MUMPS spaces have important meaning, the general syntax is: <command><space><argument><space><next_command>..., so if there is no argument of a command, it is followed by two spaces: <command><space><space><next_command>...

(Anyway, glad to see M users, or at least ex-users around here.)

Answer (score 4):

It means

```
Set A = $PIECE(P,,2)
```

> `$PIECE(string,delimiter,from)` returns
>   the substring which is the nth piece
>   of string, where the integer n is
>   specified by the from parameter, and
>   pieces are separated by a delimiter.
>   The delimiter is not returned.

The links to the documentation is here: http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20102/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_fpiece